# Awkward Java Date creation behaviour

Tags: java, date, timezone

I've just came upon a very strange behaviour of Java's Date class when I try to create two dates consequently:

```
Date startDate = new Date(1282863600000L);
System.out.println(startDate);

Date endDate = new Date(1321919999000L);
System.out.println(endDate);
```

The output is respectively:

```
Fri Aug 27 00:00:00 BST 2010
Mon Nov 21 23:59:59 GMT 2011
```

Has anyone seen something like that? Both date are initialized in an identical manner but when printed the first is shown in BST and the latter in GMT?

I tried to find explanation about that but I didn't. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you remember winding clocks forward/backward by an hour due to daylight saving? ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is documented behaviour.

From [`Date.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29):

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:

```
 dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

> `zzz` is the time zone (and may reflect daylight saving time). Standard time zone abbreviations include those recognized by the method parse. If time zone information is not available, then `zzz` is empty - that is, it consists of no characters at all.

You are using a locale that uses British Summer Time and creating a date where a day-light-saving rule applies. This would be the expected form of the date at that time to a local user.

Answer (score 1):

For me the output of this code is

```
Fri Aug 27 01:00:00 CEST 2010
Tue Nov 22 00:59:59 CET 2011
```

The exact result depends on the default locale Java is using on your system.

The difference is that [CEST is the central european summer time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time), while [CET is the central european time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time) (i.e. not summer time).

You seem to be running in a british locale (`en_GB` or similar), so your output shows the [British Summer Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) and the [Greenwich Mean Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) respectively.

The first date you specify falls into the respective summer times and the second doesn't. So Java chooses the appropriate time zone for each locale/time combination.

Answer (score 1):

After a lovely session of trying different `long` values I got this:

```
Date startDate1 = new Date(1284245999999L);
Date startDate2 = new Date(1284246000000L);
System.out.println(startDate1);
System.out.println(startDate2);

Date endDate = new Date(1321919999000L);
System.out.println(endDate);
```

The output was:

```
Sun Sep 12 01:59:59 IDT 2010
Sun Sep 12 01:00:00 IST 2010 <-- Long value is greater, but due to DST changes, actual time is one hour earlier
Tue Nov 22 01:59:59 IST 2011
```

Note that incrementing the long by `1` from `1284245999999L` to `1284246000000L` takes us "back in time" because of the transition from standard time to daylight savings time.
That is how Java time calculation behaves - the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 does not change, but the time it represents is based on the timezone.